# how to filter part of a multi-index level dataframe with different conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Here is an original dataframe,

```py
                        country2
year                        2017     2018     2019
country1                       1   2    1   2    3   6
data_provider indicator
prov_1        ind_a           45  30   22  30   30  30
prov_2        ind_a           30  30   30  30   25  30
              ind_b           30  32   30  30   30  30
prov_3        ind_b           30  30   30  35   30  28
```

and I wish to filter the column and finally get a new dataframe,

```py
# item                    country2
# year                        2017        2018     2019
# country1                       1     2     1   2    3   6
# data_provider indicator
# prov_1        ind_a         45.0   NaN  22.0 NaN  NaN NaN
# prov_2        ind_a          NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
#               ind_b          NaN  32.0   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
# prov_3        ind_b          NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
```

you can get the original dataframe by,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"data_provider": ["prov_1", "prov_1", "prov_2", "prov_2", "prov_3", "prov_3"],
          "indicator": ["ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_b", "ind_b", "ind_b"],
          "unit": ["EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR"],
          "year": ["2017", "2018","2019", "2017","2018","2019"],
          "country1": [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 6],
          "country2": [45, 22, 25, 32, 35, 28]
          }
)

df = df.pivot_table(
    index=['data_provider', 'indicator'],
    columns=['year', 'country1'],
    fill_value=30
  )
df.columns.names = ['item', 'year', 'country1']
```

here is how I get the new dataframe,

1. locate the 2 group of target column labels
   x1 = df.columns[df.columns.get_level_values(level='year')=='2017']
   x2 = df.columns[df.columns.get_level_values(level='year')=='2018']
2. get newdf1 with condition1 `df[x1]>30`
   newdf1 = df[df[x1] > 30]
3. get newdf2 with condition2 `df[x2]<30`
   newdf2 = df[df[x2] < 30]
4. update newdf2 with newdf1

```py
newdf = newdf2.combine_first(newdf1)
```

in my solution, I first get 2 dataframe after filtering the original dataframe with different conditions and then combine them together. I am wondering if there's a one direct way to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "data_provider": ["prov_1", "prov_1", "prov_2", "prov_2", "prov_3", "prov_3"],
        "indicator": ["ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_b", "ind_b", "ind_b"],
        "unit": ["EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR"],
        "year": ["2017", "2018","2019", "2017","2018","2019"],
        "country1": [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 6],
        "country2": [45, 22, 25, 32, 35, 28]
    }
)

df = df.pivot_table(
    index=['data_provider', 'indicator'],
    columns=['year', 'country1'],
    fill_value=30
)
df.columns.names = ['item', 'year', 'country1']


cond1 = (df.columns.get_level_values(level='year') == '2017') & df.gt(30)
cond2 = (df.columns.get_level_values(level='year') == '2018') & df.lt(30)
    
df_new = df.where(cond1 | cond2)
print(df_new)
```

Output :

```
                     country2                  
year                        2017       2018    2019
country1                       1   2    1   2   3   6
data_provider indicator                           
prov_1        ind_a         45.0 NaN  22.0 NaN NaN NaN
prov_2        ind_a          NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
              ind_b          NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
prov_3        ind_b          NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: the example I gave is a small sample. I am wondering if this complicated condition will also work with a large quantity of data. Anyway, we can narrow down the columns with the condition 'df.columns.get_level_values(level='year') == '2017'' first and filter out the data in those columns that larger than 30 ...?

Comment: Try and then see. Can you provide more info about your need in a new question or just update the current

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

I modified @Amira Bedhiafi's code a bit because it seemed to not generate the desired output.(I marked my output with a red circle.)

```
cond1 = (df.columns.get_level_values(level='year') == '2017') & df.gt(30)
cond2 = (df.columns.get_level_values(level='year') == '2018') & df.lt(30)
df.where(cond1 | cond2)
```

output:

[image]